# cocoon-spring-configurator version 2.2 not working in spring 6 and tomcat 10

Tags: spring, java-17, apache-cocoon

I have started working on project upgrade. Project Upgrade is to move from spring4 to spring 6 and Java 8 to Java 17.

After Updating required dependency and successful build, I have deployed war file in tomcat 10 and started getting below error

Error from tomcat log: -

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at org.apache.cocoon.spring.configurator.impl.SettingsElementParser.registerComponents(SettingsElementParser.java:136)
    at org.apache.cocoon.spring.configurator.impl.AbstractSettingsElementParser.parse(AbstractSettingsElementParser.java:144)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1390)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1370)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:96)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1437)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1245)
    ... 69 mor
```

I have gone through apache cocoon website and did not find any information about java 17 support.

Please suggest the right approach to resolve this issue or alternate solution.

Comment: What is pulling in apache cocoon? I doubt that still is in maintaince mode and I highly doubt there is a JakartaEE version.

Comment: When i checked .class file of Apache cocoon, it is pulling javax.servlet package.

Comment: As stated I highly doubt there is a JakartaEE version. I already know (from your stacktrace) that that is being pulled in. What is pulling in cocoon? What ancient technology is in use that uses cocoon.